# jquery mobile (jqm) autocomplete allow for selection using the up down keyboard arrows

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, autocomplete

I am working on my first jquery mobile application, and specifically I am using the auto-complete function. I want my application to function on both mobile and desktops. My question is this is there a way to allow for the use of up down keyboard arrows (standard desktop behavior) when wanting to select a suggested auto complete item.

jquery mobile autocomplete demo: 
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/autocomplete/

FYI - I have moved this question to https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-jqm-autocomplete-allow-for-selection-using-the-up-down-keyboard-arrows

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't found an specific solution to my question, I did find the following "plugin" to make the autocomplete allow for up down arrowing.

http://andymatthews.net/read/2012/03/27/jQuery-Mobile-Autocomplete-now-available